# How can I save protractor test results

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Is there a way to output protractor test results to a file to be viewed outside of the command line after a test is run, including seeing detailed failures?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a nice clean way of saving the test results in a orderly fashion using Jasmine reporter.

How to install and configure Jasmine reporter:

Install Jasmine reporter:

```
npm install -g jasmine-reporters
```

Add the following to the protractor-config.js file:

```
  onPrepare: function() {
    require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
      new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter('outputxmldir', true, true));
  }
```

Create the outputxmldir folder (This is where all the test outputs will be placed).

Run protractor and now the results will be exported to an XML file in the outputxmldir folder.

Comment: I did this,run "npm install jasmine-reporters" but i get a error when I call jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter, it says is undefined

Comment: Did you make sure to install it globally using the -g flag? Also, can you run your tests without the onPrepare function?

Comment: saved the require of jasmine to a variable named jasmine

Comment: the correct way is to save the output of `require('jasmine-reporters')` to it's own variable (eg, `jasmineReporters`). Then call `jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter(...)` instead of `jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter(...)`

Answer (score 7):

Just the test output is enough?

```
protractor conf.js > test.log
```

Cheers.

Comment: shot in the dark with how old this post is, but is this achievable from within the test (not console) and a dynamic path?

Answer (score 7):

You can also set the **resultJsonOutputFile** option in the config file:

```
export.config = {

   (...)

   // If set, protractor will save the test output in json format at this path.
   // The path is relative to the location of this config.
   resultJsonOutputFile:'./result.json',

   (...)

}
```

More details about the config file can be found at:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/protractor/master/docs/referenceConf.js