# how to generate logs using log4js-protractor-appender in angular/cli project using typescript

Tags: protractor

i have tried using log4js-protractor-appender for e2e testing using protractor in angular cli project by following link [Writing a log file for Protractor/Jasmine tests without using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700764/writing-a-log-file-for-protractor-jasmine-tests-without-using-command-line)

Comment: so what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use jasmine or mocha for reporting your test results. Hope it will help you. [How can I save protractor test results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634629/how-can-i-save-protractor-test-results)

Comment: thanks for the reply is there any way that generated test results to stored lnto  csv file